# How do I use jquery to set the values and text of a dropdown box from variables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, drop-down-menu

Say I have these variables:

```
  var  value1 = '';
  var textvalue1 = '';
...
```

**How do I use jquery to set the values and text of a dropdown box from these variables?**

```
 <div id"lang">
        <form name="languages" id="langSelector"> 
    <select name="file" size="1" target="_blank"> 
      <option value="VALUE">TEXT</option> 
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value=""></option>
    </select> 
  </form></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#lang').find('option').eq(0).attr('value',0)
$('#lang').find('option').eq(0).attr('text','whatever')
```

adjust eq(0) to the position of the index you require.

Comment: It's because you have a typo:  <div id"lang"> instead of  <div id="lang">

Answer (score 1):

```
$("option:eq(0)").val(textvalue1);
```

or you can use `nt-child` instead of `eq`

Comment: I'm looking for a way to select both the text value, and option value using my selectors. I have multiple dropdown boxes that are causing problems